# How Do I combine FirstName and LastName for LogonName in powershell Pro Tools?

Tags: powershell

I am using visual code with PowerShell pro tools, and I am trying to code a Windows Form using powershell and I am having trouble combing the FirstName and Lastname for the Log on name, I am fairly new to powershell pro. Below is what I have coded.

```
function New-ADUser {
param ([String]$FirstName, [String]$Lastname, [String]$logonname = "$FirstName.$LastName")
    
}
```

And this is what turns out when I generate WinForm in Powershell Pro

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$btn_Click = {
    New-ADUser -FirstName $txtFirstName.Text -Lastname $txtLastname.Text -logonname $txtlogonname.Text 
}
. 'c:\scripts\ADUSERWinform.form.designer.ps1'
$Form1.ShowDialog().
```

Is there a way or a command that stops the user from inputting information into LogonName box, and When user enter there firstname and Lastname the Logonname box will be (Firstname .Lastname)

Comment: This is better directed to the developers of/support staff at PowerShell Pro Tools, it's not strictly a PowerShell question.

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand, but I highly recommend changing the name of the function. `New-ADUser` is already [an existing cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=win10-ps) name in an official PowerShell module. You don't want to run into complications later because of the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a helper function for this I think, because it only takes one line of code to fill the LogonName box with the info provided in the first and last name boxes:

```
$btn_Click = {
    # insert the combined first and lastname into the LogonName box
    $txtlogonname.Text = '{0}.{1}' -f $txtFirstName.Text.Trim(), $txtLastname.Text.Trim()
}
```

As for your second question *"Is there a way or a command that stops the user from inputting information into LogonName box"*:
Just set the ReadOnly property of the LogonName box to $true.
From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-a-read-only-text-box-windows-forms):

> With the property set to true, users can still scroll and highlight
> text in a text box without allowing changes. A Copy command is
> functional in a text box, but Cut and Paste commands are not.

You might also want to think of a way to inform users that both first and lastname fields must contain values.
The nicest way would be to disable the button if one or both boxes are empty or whitespace only and only enable that button if both boxes have workable values.
You can do a simple test like

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($txtFirstName.Text) -or [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($txtLastname.Text)) { "Bad input" }
```

Or display an alert box if the fields are not filled in properly.